# How can I add two UIButtons side by side?

Tags: swift, uibutton, constraints, uistackview

Whenever I simulate my app the UIButtons do not appear. I get an error saying

> **Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Unable to activate constraint with anchors
>    and
>   
>   because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its
>   anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's
>   illegal.'**

How can I fix this?

```
 func setView(){

        signInButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(userSignIn), for: .touchUpInside)
        signInButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120).isActive = true
        signInButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120).isActive = true
        signInButton.setTitle("Sign in",for: .normal)

        createAnAccountButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(createAnAccount), for: .touchUpInside)
        createAnAccountButton.setTitle("Create an Account", for: .normal)
        createAnAccountButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120).isActive = true
        createAnAccountButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120).isActive = true

        let buttonStack = UIStackView()

        buttonStack.axis = NSLayoutConstraint.Axis.vertical
        buttonStack.distribution = UIStackView.Distribution.equalSpacing
        buttonStack.alignment = UIStackView.Alignment.center
        buttonStack.spacing = 16

        buttonStack.addArrangedSubview(signInButton)
        buttonStack.addArrangedSubview(createAnAccountButton)
        buttonStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        buttonStack.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        buttonStack.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        buttonStack.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 60)
        self.view.addSubview(buttonStack)

//        let barButtonSignIn = UIBarButtonItem(customView: signInButton)
//        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButtonSignIn

    }
```

Comment: addSubview before activating constraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call `addSubview` before activating constraints.